# Call asynchronous external web service in asp.net MVC controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asynchronous, external, webrequest

In the Asp.net MVC controller (GET method) I am calling external web service - for geolocation of IP - returning json data for IP location. How can I make the call to be async, hence the stack can continue while waiting the response from the service. When the GEO IP request finished I want to be able to make update to the db. Here is the current sync code:

```
public ActionResult SelectFacility(int franchiseId, Guid? coachLoggingTimeStampId)
{
    //...
    string responseFromServer = Helpers.GetLocationByIPAddress(userIpAddress);

    HomeModels.GeoLocationModel myojb = new HomeModels.GeoLocationModel();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseFromServer))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        myojb = (HomeModels.GeoLocationModel)js.Deserialize(responseFromServer, typeof(HomeModels.GeoLocationModel));

    }
    //...
}
public static string GetLocationByIPAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    Stream resStream = null;
    string responseFromServer = "";
    try
    {
        string url = GeoLocationPath.FreeGeoIP + ipAddress;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO handle this
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != resStream)
        {
            resStream.Flush();
            resStream.Close();
        }
    }
    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Any suggestion - Thread, AsyncTask ?
Thanks

Comment: WebRequest.GetResponseAsync?

Answer (score 2):

Make your ASP.NET MVC controller asynchronous:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Then use [`HttpClient.GetStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `await` its result:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SelectFacility(
    int franchiseId, Guid? coachLoggingTimeStampId)
{
    //...
    string responseFromServer = await Helpers.GetLocationByIPAddressAsync(
        userIpAddress);
    //...
}

public static async Task<string> GetLocationByIPAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(
            GeoLocationPath.FreeGeoIP + ipAddress);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noseratio. Is this thread safe?! I want to be able to insert the data from the service into the DB after the response. Does the stack will continue (display the View) while waiting for the response and then execute the async task. How then to make a call to the DB?

Comment: @DarkoSimonovski, it is as thread safe as objects used in there are. Here, a single instance of `HttpClient` here is not used by more then one thread at the same time, so it *is* thread safe. However, in ASP.NET a thread switch may occur after `after`. Further it depends on what specific DB API you're going to use. I suggest you read the articles listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info